# Why is this generic method being selected instead of a better match?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to add this extension method:

```
    public static bool Contains<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Nullable<T> value)
        where T : struct
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return source.Contains(value.Value);
    }
```

However it loops and causes a stack overflow because the last line results in a call back to this extension method, rather than `System.Linq.Contains<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T value)` method which to my mind is a better fit as the argument to `Contains` is no longer a `Nullable<T>` but just a straight `T`.

I can get around this by renaming my extension method, but I'd like to understand what's going on here.

Comment: @Charlieface: I would be hesitant to link to the VB.NET docs for a C# question.  The VB.NET rules might have been tuned to match those of C# (I don't know, I haven't checked) but the rules for overload resolution are, in any case, not shared across .NET languages as such since it's (mostly) the job of the compiler and not the runtime. Certainly both the VB.NET and the C# specs for overload resolution are complex enough that it's hard to tell at a glance if they're the same in all cases, even if they are for this particular case.

Comment: Sorry it's here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#extension-method-invocations @JeroenMostert You're quite right, that's what happens when you Google the obvious [C# overload resolution](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+overload+resolution), pick the first option and don't look too carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To answer this, we need to look at how the compiler resolves extension methods.**

Looking at [the C# spec on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#extension-method-invocations) (you can also see this in [ECMA-334](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-334_5th_edition_december_2017.pdf) 12.7.6.3):

> if the normal processing of the invocation finds no applicable methods, an attempt is made to process the construct as an extension method invocation.
> ....
>
> The objective is to find the best *type_name* `C`, so that the corresponding static method invocation can take place:
> ....
> The search for `C` proceeds as follows:
>
> - Starting with **the closest enclosing namespace declaration** *[my bold]*, continuing with each enclosing namespace declaration, and ending with the containing compilation unit, successive attempts are made to find a candidate set of extension methods:
>
>   - If the given namespace or compilation unit directly contains non-generic type declarations `Ci` with eligible extension methods `Mj`, then the set of those extension methods is the candidate set.
>   - If types `Ci` imported by *using_static_declarations* and directly declared in namespaces imported by *using_namespace_directives* in the given namespace or compilation unit directly contain eligible extension methods `Mj`, then the set of those extension methods is the candidate set.
>     ...
>     overload resolution is applied to the candidate set as described in (Overload resolution).
>     **`C` is the type within which the best method is declared as an extension method.** *[my bold]*

In other words, only one single extension class is considered if an extension method is found in it, all other extension classes are ignored.

To sum it up:

> The preceding rules mean that instance methods take precedence over extension methods, **that extension methods available in inner namespace declarations take precedence over extension methods available in outer namespace declarations** *[my bold]*, and that extension methods declared directly in a namespace take precedence over extension methods imported into that same namespace with a using namespace directive.